# Exporting Multiple Data Frames with ArcPy and Data Driven Pages?

Tags: arcpy, data-driven-pages, data-frame

I have a problem in Data Driven Pages
In my Mxd proyect I have 3 Data frames, each frame has 3 layers with their respective legends. I already activated the process of Data Driven Pages to export a single data frame with Python code, however, I need to export the other Data frames with their layers in png or pdf at the same time.

Can I export multiple data frames (with python code) and their respective layers in jpg or pdf?

This the code to export only one data frame:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT") 
for pageNum in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
  mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = pageNum
  arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG(mxd, r:c\\") ##<--- my path
```

but, I don´t know how export the other data frames using this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that you had your map saved in Data View when you ran your code and saw the undesirable result so:

1. Open your MXD in ArcMap
2. Switch to Layout View
3. Save your map
4. Run your ArcPy script

Alternatively, and probably preferably, do it all within ArcPy by changing:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
```

to:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
mxd.activeView = "PAGE_LAYOUT"
```

The `activeView` property is documented under [MapDocument](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/mapdocument-class.htm).